# How to copy exact cells into another Excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to copy some cells from a row into another Excel sheet. The cells in target sheet are not in same row.

The starting row is changing and that is why my idea is following: run a macro, choose starting row and let the macro copy all required cells to another Excel file.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: You say "run a macro" as part of your idea. What macro? Show us what you've tried so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different examples of how to copy entire rows to another worksheet. You can tweak it to fit your needs. You haven't given much detail but it seems like the key for you would be to find out exactly which row you want to copy and where you want to paste it. You'll have to provide the details of your data for us to help with that and this question.

```
Sub CopyToAnotherSheet()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Copy the last row to the last row
    wsSource.Rows(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Copy wsTarget.Rows(wsTarget.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)

    'Copy the last row to a new first row
    wsTarget.Rows(1).Insert xlDown
    wsSource.Rows(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Copy wsTarget.Rows(1)

    'Copy a particular row to another particular row
    wsTarget.Rows(7).Insert xlDown
    wsSource.Rows(3).Copy wsTarget.Rows(7)

End Sub
```